# Post date/time from HTML without using javascript

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to post the time/date on a variable from a form but I got an error saying unknown variable. This is my code

html

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <labe for="dp">Departure Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="depdate" class="form-control" id="dp">
    </div>
```

php post

```
global $fromlocation, $todestination, $depdate, $deptime;

    if(isset($_POST['btn-sf'])){
        $depdate = $_POST['date'];
        //echo $depdate;
    }
```

how to get selected date time values without using datepicker on javascript

Comment: Where is the error, on the client or server side? What does PDO have to do with this?

Comment: Add your error message.

Comment: because i am using pdo mysql

Comment: Use the _name_ of the control: `$_POST[depdate]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$depdate = $_POST['yourFormName']['date'];
```

To see what is in POST try use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: error Undefined index: deptime in C:\wamp\www\Final\client.php on line 15